# Why is my intent-filter matching URIs it shouldn't?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

My android app has an intent filter like so:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="satur9nine" android:host="*" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.satur9nine.com" android:pathPrefix="/app" />
  </intent-filter>
```

It should match satur9nine://anything or http://www.satur9nine.com/app/anything. However it is matching http://www.notmywebsite.com/app, what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation on this is fairly vague but you can kind of figure it out by seeing that in [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) docs the methods `addDataScheme`, `addDataPath` and `addDataAuthority` are all independent from each other and there is no way to add a scheme, path and authority together.

Looking at the [IntentFilter source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr0-release/core/java/android/content/IntentFilter.java#L236) confirms it. Each part of the data URI (schemas, paths, authorities) is stored in its own List, so the values from the different `<data>` elements ends up being intermingled when the matching code runs, rather than each `<data>` element being checked independently. This means the data URI can match any of the schemes with any of the hosts with any of the path prefixes which is not what is desired.

The solution is to have multiple `intent-filter` sections like so:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.satur9nine.com" android:pathPrefix="/app" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="satur9nine" android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

The intent-filter matching will run twice this way and not intermingle the schemes, hosts and paths.