# How to implement AOSP out-of-the-box experience (i.e., setup wizard)?

Tags: android, android-source, setup-wizard

I am looking to acquire some help regarding how a developer should go about creating an out-of-the-box experience (i.e., setup wizard) for AOSP. What is the proper way to utilize the [SETUP_WIZARD](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android13-release/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#5179) [Intent Category](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element) and the [USER_SETUP_COMPLETE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android13-release/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#6932) and [DEVICE_PROVISIONED](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android13-release/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#11537) [System Settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System)?

Currently, I have a standalone setup app that declares the `SETUP_WIZARD` Intent Category in [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro). My naive assumption was that on first boot (or after factory reset), if the `USER_SETUP_COMPLETE` and `DEVICE_PROVISIONED` System Settings were false, the OS would fire the `SETUP_WIZARD` Intent Category, and my setup app would then launch. Additionally, I had hoped that if the the `USER_SETUP_COMPLETE` and `DEVICE_PROVISIONED` System Settings were true, the OS would not fire the `SETUP_WIZARD` Intent Category.

My setup app is launching irrespective of the values of the `USER_SETUP_COMPLETE` and `DEVICE_PROVISIONED` System Settings (0 vs. 1).

Looking at the logs, it seems that my setup app is launching because the OS is firing a `MAIN` intent with a `HOME` category. Sadly, it seems like a `MAIN` intent with a `SETUP_WIZARD` category is **never** fired. What am I missing?

Here's my setup app's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SETUP_WIZARD" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

AOSP is a new area for me, so please be nice ;). I find that the AOSP documentation is **wildly** sparse compared to the documentation for general app devs. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you not mix multiple categories per `intent-filter`, see [Why is my intent-filter matching URIs it shouldn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440796/why-is-my-intent-filter-matching-uris-it-shouldnt) to explain why that is problematic. You should have multiple `intent-filter` sections, one for each category. Here is an example setup wizard manifest entry.

To be honest I can't remember if it is necessary to have both filters or only one is needed you can try with one or the other but having both seems fine also.

```
<activity
        android:name=".CustomSetupWizard"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:immersive="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When your Setup Wizard has done everything it needs to do it should then disable its entire package. Once disabled it won't show up unless the device is factory reset which clears the settings and re-enables the package which is what you want to happen.

Example code to complete and disable Setup Wizard:

```
  Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_PROVISIONED, 1);
  Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.USER_SETUP_COMPLETE, 1);

  // Disable and kill setup wizard
  getPackageManager().setApplicationEnabledSetting(getPackageName(),
      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```